# Null data source

Tags: java, spring

I'm making a Spring project, and I'm getting this error when I want to create a JDBC template object:

```
2015-09-25 11:58:46,260 | taskScheduler-6 |  | ERROR |       
org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:95    
|Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null
```

I declare the data source like this:

```
@Inject
private EnvironmentDataSources envDataSources;
```

And I need to make two objects, just like this:

```
@Override
public List<theObjects> getInformation() {

    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate selectOPR = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(
            envDataSources.getDataSource(EnvironmentObject1));


    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate selectUTL = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(
            envDataSources.getDataSource(EnvironmentObject2));
```

However, I'm getting that null exception. Somebody know why this happens?

Comment: Are you using Spring boot? Where are you giving the jdbc driver, username and password?

Comment: That is on the EnvironmentObjectParameter1 and EnvironmentObjectParameter2 (the schema and password to which I need to connect). Database information is on a file called database.properties.

Answer (score -1):

Add this constructor in your DAOImpl

@Autowired

public ServiceDAODataSource (dataSource) {

```
super();
setDataSource(dataSource);
```

}